Can I suspend/resume an application (Java process) dynamically using VBA?
I have an Excel sheet with multiple data columns. The data of the first column is filled by users, scanning a NFC tag, the content (MemberId) is copied to the active cell using an external commeercial tool that reads the data from an NFC reader (ACR122u-A9) and puts it in the active cell. However, when data in the other columns is entered (by desk employee, adding data related to an already scanned NFC code), I want to block the NFC input temporary, to prevent that scanned data appears in the other columns.
I implemented this using Excel's ProcessSelectionChange event: when in first column, start the external application using the Exec_TaskStartByName routine (see below) and when switching to a different column, kill it using routine Exec_TaskKillByName.
I noticed that the external program starts the JAVA framework (TaskManagement view), so kill the application in fact means kill the Java.exe process.
As such, above works, but re-starting the application each time takes too much time, resulting in a "dead-time" (tool not ready yet). Instead of killing/restarting the application each time, I am wondering if a started process can be suspended (temp stop execution) and resumed when back in the first column. Suspend/Resume is expected to take less time then kill/start.

If not, are there faster ways to start an external program other than I do (see code below)?

I noted that if I do not execute the ChDir first in the Exec_TaskStartByName routine, the application is not started.
Function Exec_TaskStartByName( _
    ByVal argFilePath As String, _
    ByVal argFileName As String, _
    ByRef argTaskId As Long)
      
    'First switch to the appropriate directory before starting the command
    ChDir (argFilePath)
    argTaskId = Shell(argFilePath & argFileName, vbMinimizedFocus)
    
    Exec_TaskStartByName = (argTaskId > 0)
    
End Function

Function Exec_TaskKillByName( _
    ByVal argFileName as string)

    Dim oServ As Object
    Dim cProc As Variant
    Dim oProc As Object
    
    Set oServ = GetObject("winmgmts:")
    Set cProc = oServ.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_Process")
    
    For Each oProc In cProc
        If (oProc.Name = argFileName) Then
            Exec_TaskKillByName = oProc.Terminate
            Exit For
        End If      
    Next
End Function

See description, starting/killing the application with the provided code works, but starting takes to much time

Rather than temporarily stopping a process, why aren't you temporarily pausing requests/responses of the other process?

In the NFC handling code, check if the user is editing a cell https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/excel-check-user-edit-cell/ - if they are, don't insert the NFC data.

So you are looking for a command that will pause the JVM and another command that will let the JVM resume execution, correct? Alternatively, is modifying the Java code an option or maybe replacing the Java program with a different program - not necessarily written in Java?

@DuncG: The other process is a desk employee (at sport club) that adds data to previously registered users. Of caue the desk employee can wait his/her turn, but in practice, this does not work (time). When NFC input is not halted, registration data appears at the fields that he is currenlty editing, which required manual correction and takes time. This is why I want to control the NFC scanner input.

@Abra: the tool that reads NFC data and put it in an receiving tool(for us: excel) is an external commercial tool, that I cannot modify. Reason for refering to Java is that I noticed this tool starts Java (seen in task manager).  I was wondering is there is a method that this can be paused (Windows 11 level), and if so , how to do this in VBA

@AndyTurner: As mentioned, I do not own the NFC handling code (external tool). I can only start and stop it with the two routines provided. If  a JAVA process can be halted, it needs to be done on Windows 11 (OS) level

@user26618353 I mean the place in your code where you consume the events from the external tool.

look for https://github.com/CRaC
